# OWL - How to specify that an object is not linked twice with another object via the same objectProperty

Tags: duplicates, owl

I have an Student object that is enrolled (propertyObject) with a Course.
I need to restrict that the same student cannot be enrolled in the same course more than 1 time.
How to write that in OWL/Protégé?
Please!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the restriction, it is implicit in the language.

You have individual A, a student, and individual B, a course.

If you try to specify that A is enrolled in B twice, you have two axioms:

```
A isEnrolledIn B
A isEnrolledIn B
```

OWL ontologies are /sets/ of axioms, therefore the two axioms disappear and only one is left.